# repeatWhen does not work after subscribeOn

Tags: rx-java

Running the following code with `subscribeOn` **excluded**

```
PublishSubject<Void> repeatSubject = PublishSubject.create();

Observable.
    <Integer>create(subscriber -> {
        System.out.println("1");
        subscriber.onNext(1);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }).
    //subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).
    repeatWhen(h -> h.flatMap(nothing -> repeatSubject)).
    subscribe();

repeatSubject.onNext(null);
```

prints, as expected, **two '1'**.

But as only I uncomment `subscribeOn`, the only **one '1'** is printed. Must be `repeatWhen` does not resubscribe to observable. Why?

P.S. Thanks **yosriz** for good explanation. So now question is not 'why', but 'how'. How could I, from main thread, repeat observable, scheduled on another thread?

P.P.S. The following modification still prints one '1'.

```
    BehaviorSubject<Void> repeatSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
    Observable.
            <Integer>create(subscriber -> {
                System.out.println("1");
                subscriber.onNext(1);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .repeatWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Void>, Observable<?>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Void> observable) {
                    return observable.zipWith(repeatSubject, new Func2<Void, Void, Object>() { // called on main thread
                        @Override
                        public Object call(Void aVoid, Void aVoid2) {
                            return new Object(); // never called !
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
    repeatSubject.onNext(null); // called on main thread
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because in the first case when you didn't specify `Scheduler`, the subscribe happens immediately on this thread in blocking fashion, so when the `repeatWhen` subscribed to the `repeatSubject`, it didn't emit yet. so the `flatMap` happens before you call to `repeatSubject.onNext(null);`.
That means that at first, the `flatMap` subscribed to the `repeatSubject` and only then the `onNext(null)` got called and the `repeatWhen` resubscribed to the source `Observable`.

When you do specify the Scheduler, the all `Observable` sequence got scheduled on a separate thread, so the `repeatSubject.onNext(null);` **might** happens before the `flatMap` subscribed to the repeatSubject, (you don't have any guarantee as the two operations happens in two different threads) so it's missed the notification, and thus the repeat didn't work.

You can observe the behavior by adding log:

```
Observable.
            <Integer>create(subscriber -> {
                System.out.println("1");
                subscriber.onNext(1);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }).
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).
            repeatWhen(h -> h.flatMap(nothing -> {
                System.out.println("repeatWhen flatMap");
                return repeatSubject;
            })).
            subscribe();

    System.out.println("repeatSubject.onNext");
    repeatSubject.onNext(null);
```

**EDIT:**

**How to repeat:**

You can use `zip` in order to sync together both completed emission and your `Subject.onNext()` emissions, with this way, each `onNext()` will repeat the sequence single time:

```
     Observable.
            <Integer>create(subscriber -> {
                System.out.println("1");
                subscriber.onNext(1);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .repeatWhen(completeNotfications -> 
                  completeNotfications.zipWith(repeatSubject, (o, aVoid) -> new Object()))
            .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! But how can I, on main thread, repeat observable scheduled on another thread?

Comment: Still prints one '1' after repeatSubject.onNext(null). Updated post with code I'm trying.

Comment: can you elaborate from where and when are you calling the `repeatSubject.onNext(null)`?

Comment: I have updated post with exact code I run. repeatSubject.onNext(null) is called just after Observable subscription, in main thread. Also I noticed that zipWith is not calling.